# Can I ask ATC a radio check with a handheld radio?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications

I bought a handheld portable radio capable of transmitting in the air band and I was wondering if I can request a radio check to the ATC to see if the radio works properly. I know it's illegal to talk over those frequencies unless you're an aircraft (or at least I suppose it is), but I wonder if it's ok in this case.

If it's ok to use that channel just to test the radio, what's the best way to go about it? Just "Radio check"? Or "<Airport> tower/ground, radio check"? Or should I acknowledge the fact that I'm not an aircraft with something like "<Airport> tower/ground, on the ground with a portable radio, radio check"? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a radio license?

Comment: No I don't. To add more color, I'm a student pilot so I do plan to use my radio legally (if necessary).

Comment: Please indicate what jurisdiction you are in. The radio rules are quite different between different countries.

Comment: I'd add that even with a (ham) radio license, most if not all countries would consider this illegal. You're free to receive any frequency, but to transmit in certain frequency bands, you need a proper license for that frequency.

Comment: @jayded-bee Receiving any frequency is illegal in many countries. Even receiving air-band is illegal by default in many countries.

Comment: This is in the US.

Comment: @user253751 Nobody can stop you from listening to the EM waves traveling through the air, because it is impossible to know whenever somebody is receiving the signal. Reverse-engineering encryption and thus snooping on data that is not intended for you may be illegal, but that's a different issue. Receiving is not traceable.

Comment: @jayded-bee there is a difference between "legal" and "illegal but they probably won't catch you". Look what the British government did to Alan Turing.

Comment: @user253751 If owning a radio station is illegal where they live then OP has other problems

Comment: Clearly the answer is yes. Whether or not the regulations specifically allow or prohibit it is another matter altogether. It's unlikely that you'd ever make it to the airport without violating the letter of some local, state, or federal regulation - there are just too many.

Comment: @jayded-bee Note that I said "receiving any frequency" and not "owning a radio station". It's hard to see your comment as anything other than bad faith.

Comment: @user253751 how is commenting on an internet forum "bad faith"? I don't see how it could be legal to own a radio station capable of receiving radio signals yet illegal to actually receive them? That is completely unenforceable. I'd like to know which countries have inane laws like this.

Comment: @jayded-bee because I said "it's illegal to receive any frequency" and you decided to interpret that as "it's illegal to own a radio station"

Comment: @user253751 yes, because that was the logical conclusion for me, as explained above. What strikes me as odd is the continued claim that such laws exist *somewhee* but not a single example; I could say the same of your comments, but I'm more interested in learning than in calling out my assumptions of other people's intentions. Take that as you will, I don't consider users on here to be boogeymen.

Comment: @jayded-bee same laws as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_scanner#Legislation

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think there's a technicality here.  Both the operator and the radio *station* each need, independently, an FCC license.  The operator license requirement has been waived for pilots for a long time, and in 1996 the requirement for the plane to have a station license was dropped so long as the airplane is in US airspace.  When you operate a handheld in the plane, you are operating a second radio within the same station (the airplane) so you are covered on both counts.

The problem is outside the plane you are not operating in a licensed or license-waived station, so you would need a station license for the radio, AND you'd need a restricted radio-telephone operator's permit because you don't fall under the pilot waiver because you're not flying a plane.

Virtually ANY ATC facility will not know any of this and will almost certainly give you a radio check.  It would be a very rare circumstance that anyone would call you out.  I wouldn't do it on clearance delivery at O'Hare, but elsewhere it's unlikely anyone will care.  Unlikely they'd even ask for a tail number if you said "Rochester Ground, how do you read?"

But as the previous poster points out, it is *technically* illegal and can have consequences.  I have both FCC and FAA licenses and I too have heard of people being convicted for transmitting on public service frequencies.  So I'll clarify...  If you are a pilot, AND you are at the airport, and you are making a legitimate radio check, it is technically prohibited but you would have some latitude that a layperson would not.  But if you are not a licensed pilot to begin with, it's probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 18):

The key is in a comment to the original question:

> I'm a student pilot so I do plan to use my radio legally (if necessary).

which leads to two possible answers:

1 - Talk to your instructor. They should be familiar with procedures for handling this.

2 - Use it on a plane. Bring it with you on a flight. Then test it from inside the plane, which should be legitimate as you are then testing it as a backup radio for legitimate use, and can actually identify yourself as a pilot of an actual aircraft if questioned.

Comment: Test it in the plane, while on ground, just to avoid any potential issues, like student task saturation, interference due to faulty equipment or any of the potentially complicating factors not needed when airborne.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You will be just fine. I’ve done it many many times before.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer? E.g., in what jurisdiction were you in? What licenses did you have? What were some (example) circumstances (at home? at an airport? Time of day? Purpose of the test? Etc.)? Distance to the ATC tower? What was the transmit power level?

Comment: This is in the US.  I can’t imagine any controller else where in the world would have such a stick up his @ss as to be annoyed by such a request.  This is being done insure that one can establish two way communications, and only a real idiot/goon would complain about such a thing.

Comment: @CarloFelicione You should [edit] your answer to include this information, rather than separating it from your answer in a comment.

Comment: Are we trying to set a record for just how pedantic and puerile we can be here in the comments? It's ridiculous, and reflects poorly on our community.

Answer (score 2):

Ground stations have to be licensed to transmit on ATC frequencies. To get a license you will need to have a legitimate reason for the use of the radio. Until then, do not transmit on ATC frequencies. During my career, a man got a year in federal prison for the unauthorized use of a portable radio. It is considered interference with the ATC system.

Comment: Was he a pilot doing legitimate aviation-related stuff? Or some rando interfering with aviation safety?

Comment: Rando interference

Comment: Well, there you go.

Comment: @RetiredATC by requesting spurious radio checks?